# List of functions with defined signature in Dart

Tags: dart

In Dart, is it possible to have a list of functions that have a well defined signature? I'm looking for something like

```
List<(int, int) -> int> listOfFunctions;
```

which is of course wrong.

I can do

```
List<Function> listOfFunctions;
```

but then I don't know the signature.

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just create a typedef for your function

```
typedef int MyFunction(int a, int b);

List<MyFunction> listOfFunctions;
```